# jQuery validate plugin - delegated form submit event not firing

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

```jquery
$("form").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
         form.submit();
    }
});
$(document).on("submit", "form", function() {
    alert("submit");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mayko/g1715wqn/

- Why does the alert never get fired?
- How can I make it work?

---

**Update:**

Funny that, this works:

```
$("form").on("submit", function() {
    alert("does work");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mayko/g1715wqn/5/

@ Sparky:
I'm working on a abandon page dialog plugin. Therefore need to listed to actual form submits  of all forms on the page (with or without the validator). Also these form can be loaded asynchronous. I think $(document).on("submit", "form", function); seems to be the right event to listen to.

Comment: Please do not rely solely on the jsFiddle to show us the relevant HTML markup.

Answer (score 2):

**There is no reason why you would use BOTH the plugin's provided `submitHandler` callback function and an external `submit` event handler.**  Whatever you're doing can easily be contained within one of these two handlers.  (You also have not explained what you're ultimately trying to achieve with these handlers.)

---

**Quote OP**:

> *"Why does the alert never get fired?"*

The `submitHandler` callback function blocks the default `submit` event of the form, so for example, you could use `ajax` instead.  This is why your external `submit` event handler is never firing.

In your case, the `submitHandler` callback is completely superfluous as the code contained within also happens to be the plugin's default...

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
    form.submit(); // this is the default
}
```

You could remove the option above and then your custom event handler would fire.  However, that's not necessarily the most correct way to fire some code upon the submit event while using this plugin.

---

**Quote OP**:

> *"How can I make it work?"*

Whatever it is you're planning to do with this external `submit` event handler, I suggest you handle it instead within the provided `submitHandler` callback method. (that's why it's available to you.)

This is how it should be done...

```
$("form").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        alert("submit");
        form.submit();
    }
});
```

*(In the case of submitting the form with `.ajax()`, you'd remove the `form.submit()` line and replace it with a `return false`.)*

```js
$("form").validate({
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    alert("submit");
    form.submit();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<form method="POST">
  <input type="text" required />
  <br />
  <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have used the `submtHandler` option, the validator framework will prevent the default action and stop event propagation that is why the delegation submit handler is not working.

So one possible solution is not to use the submit handler....

```js
$("form").validate({});
$(document).on("submit", "form", function() {
  alert("submit");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<form method="POST" novalidate>
  <input type="text" required />
  <br />
  <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: You've misspelled `submitHandler`.  Why recommend removing the `submitHandler` in favor of an external `submit` event handler?  The way to fix the problem is to simply move the `alert` into the `submitHandler` and remove the external event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Working [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g1715wqn/3/)

Remove `submtHandler`

```
$("form").validate({});
$(document).on("submit", "form", function () {
    alert("submit");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

my working solution if we want delegate dynamic form and use with validate plugin:

```html
$('#parent').on('submit', '#child', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault()
      
   $(this).validate({
    rules:{
       // validate rules 
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
       // do ajax call
    }
   })
   
   $(this).submit()
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Change the

```
            <button type="submit" class="btn">Submit</button>
```

To

```
            <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Submit"/>
```

Comment: [Makes absolutely no difference whatsoever](http://jsfiddle.net/g1715wqn/4/).  This plugin works just as well with `type="submit"`, even when it's a `button` element; and the `value` attribute would simply change the label of the button, which is already `Submit` by default.